# POST to web form using CURL & BASH

Tags: bash, post, curl

I'm trying, without success, to use cURL to post data to the form on this URL:

https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml

how can i correctly send the request to the server?

I've analysed the post data with chrome (right click, inspect element, network tab), copy as CURL:

```
curl 'https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=!hh6JmwccX43y6ULiN5rkqiT19gIki8NN0dqDBgaDtQ+kRKM3qulJksgmqjFkb1N+dmFkEA5UteMiyTaLuahx481KkIte4g==; NIC=1007948204.20480.0000; TS2785e3=62b722def584484a84a892fda4181cd30f4798093eac408f542740be60ac0ec5d6bd720d4045274b4076e350; TS2785e3_77=5412_a812844049fdca3a_rsb_0_rs_https%3A%2F%2Fnic.ar%2FbuscarDominio.xhtml_rs_0_rs_0' -H 'Origin: https://nic.ar' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: https://nic.ar/buscarDominio.xhtml' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'busquedaDominioForm2=busquedaDominioForm2&javax.faces.ViewState=3588315592207743676%3A-7314103686046665250&busquedaDominioForm2%3Adominio=example&busquedaDominioForm2%3Aj_idt56=2&busquedaDominioForm2%3AbtnBuscar=Consultar' --compressed
```

But when i run that get empty response from server

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at: http://superuser.com/a/149335/340330

Comment: I've tried that, but there are some strange strings in this particular form i cant find out how to post.

Comment: I see that there are 3 forms on that page, with id & name of "j_idt13", "loginForm", and "busquedaDominioForm2". I _assume_ you need to login correctly before you can send data to either of the other two forms. Note that all 3 forms have action="/buscarDominio.xhtml". So I guess that the server is aliasing the xhtml page name to a (PHP or other) CGI program that actually serves the page and processes form submission actions. Sorry I can't answer your question, but I figured that info may be helpful for someone who is an expert in this topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446105/using-curl-to-post-data-to-a-form

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?