# How to automate interaction for a website with POST method

Tags: python, selenium, mechanize

I need to input text into the text box on this website:

```
http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html
```

I then need the return page's html to be returned. I have looked at other solutions. But i am aware that there is no solution for all. I have seen selenium, but im do not understand its documentation and how i can apply it. Please help me out thanks.

BTW i have some experience with beautifulsoup, if it helps.I had asked before but requests was the only solution.I don't know how to use it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulled straight from the docs and changed to your example.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the page
driver.get("http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html")

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

# find the element that's name attribute is Sentence
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Sentence")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("You're welcome, now accept the answer!")

# submit the form 
inputElement.submit()
```

This will at least help you input the text.  Then, take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861775/python-selenium-accessing-html-source) to retrieve the html.

Comment: Thanks Bud. Update. I can access the URL with ".current_url". However your example doesn't work for returning html.

Answer (score 1):

First, imho automation via BeautifulSoup is overkill if you're looking at a single page. You're better off looking at the page source and get the form structure off it. Your form is really simple:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST"
ACTION="/cgi-bin/link/construct-page-4.cgi#submit">
<input type="text" name="Sentence" size="120" maxlength="120"></input><br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="Constituents" CHECKED>Show constituent tree &nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="NullLinks" CHECKED>Allow null links &nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="AllLinkages" OFF>Show all linkages &nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="LinkDisplay" VALUE="on">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="ShortLength" VALUE="6">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="PageFile" VALUE="/docs/submit-sentence-4.html">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="InputFile" VALUE="/scripts/input-to-parser">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="Maintainer" VALUE="sleator@cs.cmu.edu">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit one sentence">
<br>
</FORM>
```

so you should be able to extract the fields and populate them.

I'd do it with `curl` and `-X POST` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446085/using-curl-to-post-data-to-a-form) -- see the answer too :)).

If you really want to do it in python, then you need to do something like [POST using requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: yep.  this is definitely better to use a simple curl rather than use any framework just to return html.  +1

Comment: Well i have to do this in python. There is another answer below, which has made the input a cake walk. If only you could help with extracting the html source back.

Answer (score 0):

Following OP's requirement of having the process in python.

I wouldn't use selenium, because it's launching a browser on your desktop and is overkill for just filling up a form and getting its reply (you could justify it if your page would have JS or ajax stuff).

The form request code could be something like:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'Sentence': 'Once upon a time, there was a little red hat and a wolf.',
    'Constituents': 'on',
    'NullLinks': 'on',
    'AllLinkages': 'on',
    'LinkDisplay': 'on',
    'ShortLegth': '6',
    'PageFile': '/docs/submit-sentence-4.html',
    'InputFile': "/scripts/input-to-parser",
    'Maintainer': "sleator@cs.cmu.edu"
}

r = requests.post("http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/link/construct-page-4.cgi#submit", 
                  data=payload)

print r.text
```

the `r.text` is the HTML body which you can parse via e.g. BeautifulSoup.

Looking at the HTML reply, I think your problem will be in processing the text within the `<pre>` tags, but that's an entirely different thing outside the scope of this question.

HTH,